# Generate JSON From Mysql Using PHP and Customize it

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to structure data that I fetch from MySQL database to a custom format to enable me load the data into my Android views.
I was able to achieve it in Firebase but am apparently having issues with structuring the same format when fetching the data from MySQL DB.

Attached is a screenshot of how i want to structure my JSON Array
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VbC4.jpg

Below is my code

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($con,"conkev_ob")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql = "select rim, name, type from t_customer"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$jsonEmployee = array();
$jsonIndividual = array();
$jsonCorporate = array();
$jsonBank = array();
$jsonGroup = array();
$jsonMinor = array();
$jsonCombined = array();
$finalJsonString = "";
$jsonTitle = array();



if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($row["type"] == "E"){

        $jsonEmployee['Employee'][] = $row;


    }
    else if($row["type"] == "C"){

        $jsonCorporate['Corporate'][] = $row;


    }
    else if($row["type"] == "I"){

        $jsonIndividual['Individual'][] = $row;


    }
    else if($row["type"] == "B"){

        $jsonBank['Bank'][]  = $row;


    }
    else if($row["type"] == "G"){

        $jsonGroup['Group'][] = $row;


    }
    else if($row["type"] == "M"){

        $jsonMinor['Minor'][] = $row;


    }
    else{
        die("cannot connect"); 
    }

}
$finalJsonString = $jsonEmployee + $jsonIndividual  + $jsonCorporate+ 
$jsonBank+ $jsonGroup+ $jsonMinor;
$jsonCombined['data']= $finalJsonString;

}

mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode($jsonCombined);
```

Comment: Is there a way i can structure the sections in dynamic way without manually setting them?

Comment: In PHP concatenating is done with "." (dot), not with + (plus). $finalJsonString = $jsonEmployee + $jsonIndividual  + $jsonCorporate+ 
$jsonBank+ $jsonGroup+ $jsonMinor;

Comment: Thank you Dimitrov for your feedback. I was more like trying to combine the arrays. And using the + operator did magic for me. But thanks again for pointing that out. Am still learning $php